# .$ notation in nuxt3 and accessing it

Tags: nuxt3, keycloak-js

I am using `keycloak-js` in my `Nuxt3` app. There is this line in the plugin code ...

```
app.$keycloak = keycloak;
```

How can I access the value stored in `app.$keycloak` in my `pages (pages/*.vue)`?

Of specific interest to me is the `token (access_token)`. How can I get it?

And I want the ability to `auto inject` the `Authorization: Bearer <token>` header whenever I make a call to `/api/...` endpoints of an external server. How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get it working in a page thus ...

```
<template>
  {{ useNuxtApp().$keycloak }}
</template>
```